# xrdb -load ~/.Xdefaults cpp: too many input files

Tags: cygwin, x-windows, xterm

#### Question:

- Why doesn't this work?

#### Note:

`# cat ~/.Xdefaults`

```
XTerm*background: black
XTerm*foreground: white
XTerm*highlightColor: red
XTerm*highlightSelection: true
```

`# xrdb -load ~/.Xdefaults`

```
cpp: too many input files
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cpp reports this error if it receives more than two arguments on the command line.

On what OS are you running?  Is there a non-standard version of cpp in your `$PATH`?  You can try replacing cpp with a wrapper script to find out what it's really doing or use "strace" to see how it's being called.

Hold on, I think I've got it: the path to your directory contains whitespace.  Watch this:

```
  $ mkdir '/tmp/this path contains spaces'
  $ HOME='/tmp/this path contains spaces' sh
  $ cd ~
  $ pwd
  /tmp/this path contains spaces
  $ touch testfile
  $ xrdb ~/testfile
  cpp: too many input files
```

Let me know if this is an accurate assessment.

Comment: @larsks: Thanks! I had white space in $PATH - Win NT 5.1, Cygwin